# Perform an Inner Join in Zend PHP Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I want to perform an inner join on two table.

Table A -

item_id

item_title

varX

Table B -

item_id

varY

someVar

This is how I've done this using a RAW SQL query.

```
$sql = 'SELECT tableA.item_id, tableY.item_title AS Name, 5 * varX +  5 * count(*) AS myScore 
FROM tableA 
INNER JOIN tableY ON tableA.item_id=tableY.item_id 
WHERE someVar=\'8\' 
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY myScore DESC
LIMIT 10';
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Now I want to do this using a Zend Query.

This is what I've written -

```
$data = $this->_db->select()
->from(array('tablA'=>'tableA'), array('item_id', 'item_title'), 'myScore'=>'(5*'tableA'.'varX') + 5*count(*)')
->joinInner(array('tablB'=>'tableB'), 'tablA'.'item_id' = 'tablB'.'item_id')
->where('someVar = 8')
->GROUP('item_id')
->order('myScore DESC')
->limit(10);

$dataResult = $this->_db->fetchAll($data);
```

But I get this error -

```
 syntax error, unexpected '=&gt;' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'
```

in line *->from(array('tablA'=>'tableA'), array('item_id', 'item_title'), 'myScore'=>'(5*'tableA'.'varX') + 5*count(*)')*

Not sure what to do do here as I've read the official documentation but still can't figure this out. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which Zend Framework Version do you use?

Comment: It's version 1.12.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes were used in wrong way in your code. Also, tt seems like, you have used the unnecessary third parameter for `'myScore'` field. It should be placed in the second parameter
Try the following:

```
...
$data = $this->_db->select()
->from(array('tablA'=>'tableA'), array('item_id', 'item_title', 'myScore'=>'(5 * tableA.varX) + 5*count(*)'))
->joinInner(array('tablB'=>'tableB'), 'tablA.item_id = tablB.item_id')
->where('someVar = 8')
->group('tablA.item_id')
->order('myScore DESC')
->limit(10);
```

Comment: @chautob0t, It's about the unnecessary third parameter. See my update

Comment: Now I get this, 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ')' in line _->joinInner(array('tablB'=>'tableB'), 'tablA.item_id = tablB.item_id')_

Comment: probably, one bracket is missed. Try again the last updated version. It should work

Comment: I already tried with the bracket, still the same error. Trying to figure out what the actual problem is.

Comment: strange, on the first glance, there's no other errors in syntax in that code fragment

Comment: This finally worked, although I needed to change this _->group('item_id')_ to this _->group('tablA.item_id')_ and needed to fix a configuration error in MySQL server. 
If you can please update your answer to have this: _->group('tablA.item_id')_, I can mark it as accepted. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Cheers.